# Passing "unlimited" values through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a filter for google maps api on our site so people can choose to display information only related to locations that are checked. I'm not sure the best way to pass unlimited parameters through ajax due to being relatively new at it. Each location is available to be selected by checking the corresponding checkbox. Here is my code I'm trying to pass below.

```
 //Example Checkbox
 <input type="checkbox" checked name="locationID1" class="locationID" value="47">

 $(".layer-button").click(function(){
        var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
        var locationID = [];
        var n = 0;
        $(".locationID", form).each(function () {
            if(this.checked){
                // part I'm having troubles with.
                locationID[n] = $(this).val();
                n++;
            }
        });

        var data = {
                "action":"addLayer",
                "map-try-ok":"1",
                // part I'm having troubles with.
                "location_id":locationID
        }


       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/map/map.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery.each( data, function( key, val ) {   
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var color = $("select[name=color]", form).val();
                var address = val["address"];
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if(results){
                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            icon: "../image/icons/map/icon_marker"+color+".png",
                            title: val["name"],
                            url: ""
                        });
                    }
                });

            });




        },
        error: function(){return false;}
    });

});
```

The code works great if I'm passing static numbers like.

```
        var data = {
                "action":"addLayer",
                "map-try-ok":"1",
                "location_id":"47"
        }
```

Is there an optimal way of passing arrays through data passed through ajax? I'm not sure if its possible to run an each function right in the parameters of var data?

UPDATE:

I'm passing all this information to PHP script. PHP's return info to jquery works fine and I'm having no problems with the actual Google Maps API itself. The issue is passing [x] variables from jquery -> ajax -> php

I've attempted to call location_id with the following code and it completely passes the chunk of code leading me to believe the passing of the array did not work.

```
     if(is_array($_POST['location_id'])){
        foreach($_POST['location_id'] as $location_id){
            echo "ID: ".$location_id."<br />";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your location locationID variable is an array. Are you even allowed to pass an array to the `location_id parameter`? You would need to check API but that's probably where your problem lies.

Comment: Yes that is where I'm not sure where to go from. I'm pretty sure you cant but I don't know the proper way of passing x variables. The api has nothing to do with this particular issue. Its getting the location_ids from jquery -> ajax -> php. The return works properly.

Comment: Have you tried alerting or Console.logging locationID to confirm that it is being populated?

Comment: Yep I've done that and it is.

Comment: var_dump the $_POST array to see exactly what your PHP script is getting

Answer (score 0):

`locationID` as an array will give you `$_POST['location_id']` as an array in your php script. You can just loop through them with a foreach loop

```
foreach ($_POST['location_id'] as $location_id){
    //do something with $location_id
}
```

Comment: Check out my update to my question. I did something similar to this already and it ignores the section and says that $_POST['location_id'] is not an array

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The current code does work properly.

Long answer:

Alright guys I'm sorry, I'm new to ajax and I found my problem... In trying to test to see if it was being passed properly I was changing dataType from "json" to "html" since I was no longer returning an array, but returning an echo to print to the screen. I did not realize json was required for both passing arrays and returning arrays and this is why I could never get a method to work. I eventually found in my php error logs it trying to hit the code and saw it was in fact passing the variables from the array.

Comment: `I did not realize json was required for both passing arrays and returning arrays` that is incorrect. `dataType: 'json',` is only for the data being retrieved from the server and has nothing to do with the data being sent to the server.